# Storing the active class data in localStorage of browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to store the active class of the clicked link in localStorage when i navigate to other page. How to do it?

```html
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active" style="background-color: #394263; color: white"><a id="a" style="color: white">A</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263; color: white"><a id="p" style="color: white">P</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263; color: white"><a id="s" style="color: white">S</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Share what did you try till now so that we can understand how you change the active class and what to do for your requirement.

Comment: hello, I don't know much about jquery..so i couldn't proceed any further how to change the active class. I just used bootstrap for it. When i go to different link,the active class wouldn't change.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage to store info that you need, then test the value and add a class to the one button clicked earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a id for each list..

```
<body onload = "check_storage()">
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active" id="id1" onclick= "active("id1")"><a id="a" style="color: white">A</a</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id = "id2" onclick = "active("id2")"><a id="p" style="color: white">P</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id = "id3" onclick = "active("id3")"><a id="s" style="color: white">S</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In JavaScript create funtion to store the id in localstorage

```
//onload of your page this will get called
 function check_storage() {
    //check if there is any value in localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem("listId") != null) {
    //get that value
    var val= localStorage.getItem("listId");
    console.log(val);
    setActive(val); //call function
     }
     }

 function active(id) {
localStorage.removeItem('listId');//clear previous data
localStorage.setItem("listId", id);//add data to storage
console.log(id);
      }

 function setActive(value) {
document.getElementById(value).classList.value = "list-group-item active";
    }
```

On loading of the body of the page, it checks for the id in localstorage and make that id the active group. Upon calling active function, it clears previously stored data and adds the current id to local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every `a` has an `id`, you can set it with [`Storage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

```
localStorage.setItem(
  'activeListGroupItem',
  $('#collapse2 .list-group-item.active a').attr('id')
);
```

Then you can get it and apply it back with [`Storage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem):

```
$('#' + localStorage.getItem('activeListGroupItem'))
  .parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Hey... what does # defines in 2nd method

Comment: @Shockwave `#` it's the `id`-selector in jQuery syntax (deriving from CSS)